# Redux mutations boolean

Tags: redux

This might be a silly questions, but i'm using Redux for an React application, and i need to store some application state as boolean values.
When im picking up an action in a reducer, i need to set the boolean to the opposit of the current. Currently im doing this with:

```
export default function(state = true, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    case 'SOME_ACTION_TYPE':
        return action.payload;
    }
    return state;
}
```

The action.payload already holds the correct value, but can i just assign it as im doing now, or am i mutating the state? Can you even mutate it as it's a boolean?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
export default function(state = true, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'SOME_ACTION_TYPE':
    return !state;
  }
   return state;
}
```

Hope it can help

Comment: I think this is correct, you don't need a payload if all the action does is flip the boolean in the state.

Comment: I just need to know if i should somehow take a copy, as we do with objects and arrays, or if this is enough to prevent state mutations

Comment: You can test it easily :
```var objA = { a: 1}
var objB = objA;
objB.a = 2;
console.log(objA.a) /* return 2 */

/* but */
var boolA = true;
var boolB = boolA;
boolB = !boolB;
console.log(boolB, boolA) // return false, true
```